# Referring to function parameters inside a Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have a function like this in Postgres 9.5:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func (p1 date, p2 integer, p3 integer, p4 integer) RETURNS
SETOF some_datum AS $func$
        BEGIN
                RETURN QUERY
                with t as (
                    select p4, postcode, p1, rent * 12 * 100 / nullif(price, 0) as result
                      FROM crosstab (
                        $$
                          select postcode::text, indicator::int, value::float
                          from my_data
                          where (indicator = p2 or indicator = p3) and date = p1
                          order by 1,2
                        $$)
                      AS ct (
                        "postcode" text,
                        "price" float,
                        "rent" float)
                )
                select * from t where result is not null;
        END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I load it with `PSQL` I get back the error:

```
ERROR:  column "p2" does not exist
LINE 4:                           where (indicator = p2 ...
                                                     ^
QUERY:  
                          select postcode::text, indicator::int, value::float
                          from my_data
                          where (indicator = p2 or indicator = p3) and date = p1
                          order by 1,2
```

I tried to prefix the `p2` etc with `my_func.` but it doesn't work. 
How can I refer to a function parameter in that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crosstab just sees a string, so send a good string.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func (p1 date, p2 integer, p3 integer, p4 integer) RETURNS
SETOF some_datum AS $func$
        BEGIN
                RETURN QUERY
                WITH t AS (
                    SELECT p4, postcode, p1, rent * 12 * 100 / nullif(price, 0) as result
                      FROM crosstab (
                        format(
                          $$
                            SELECT postcode::text, indicator::int, value::float
                            FROM my_data
                            WHERE (indicator = %s or indicator = %s)
                              AND date = '%s'
                            ORDER BY 1,2
                          $$,
                          p2,
                          p3,
                          p1
                        )
                      )
                      AS ct (
                        "postcode" text,
                        "price" float,
                        "rent" float)
                )
                select * from t where result is not null;
        END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Btw, if you're going to used named params, p1, p2, p3, etc are a bad idea. They're already `$1, $2, $2`. I would suggested at least something a little easier to follow like `indicator1, indicator2`

Comment: Yes the variables have different names (I just stripped out the query as too long). Also, it should be `date = %s` like `date = '%s'`?

Comment: @Randomize No single quotes, that's the purpose of the format(%s) it does literal escaping (%I does identifier escaping).

Comment: strange, I get an error without and it works with quotes.

Comment: I take that back, it requires single quotes if the parameter types are strings. my bad.

Comment: @Randomize only date should need the quotes btw.

Comment: sure, `p1 = '2017-06-01', p2 = 3, p3 = 5`

Comment: Under normal circumstances you could make this faster, but the downside to cross tab is that it only takes its argument as a string. =( So you have to convert everything to text and back.